# How do I build Bitcoin source in Windows 7?

Tags: development, windows, compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup

I am trying to build the current Bitcoin source in Windows 7x64 - Does anyone know of an idiot-proof tutorial? Some of the steps in the [included doc](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-msw.txt) give me errors.

When I try to tar openssl with msys, I get symlink errors.

Is there a better walk-through?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [Windows Build Instructions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5851.msg86700#msg86700) By Matt Corallo, it's outdated, but has some additional comments to the [included doc](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-msw.txt).

> **Install:**
>
> - MinGW Automated Installer from
>     http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/OldFiles/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20110316/.
>     Install with the C++ and MSYS options checked.
> - Activestate Perl (for building openssl) from
>     http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads.  You don't need
>     anything except ActivePerl and Perl, none of the other fancy crap.
>     You do want to add Perl to your PATH (its an option in the
>     installer).
>
> **Download:**
>
> - WxWidgets 2.9.1:
>     http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/2.9.1/wxWidgets-2.9.1.zip/download.
>     Unzip to C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1-mgw
> - OpenSSL 1.0.0d:
>     http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0d.tar.gz.     Untar  to
>     C:\openssl-1.0.0c-mgw (yes bitcoin is designed to build with
>     1.0.0c, but might as well use the latest version since it works right?) Hint: untar using the tar binary which is included in MinGW (do not use 7-zip, [it will not handle symlinks correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102873/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-with-cygwin-and-mingw-in-openssl)) using cd \c\ && tar xvvf\c\Users\Matt\Downloads\openssl-1.0.0d.tar.gz && mv openssl-1.0.0d openssl-1.0.0c-mgw in the msys shell
> - Berkeley DB 4.7.25 NC: http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.7.25.NC.zip.  Unzip to C:\db-4.7.25.NC-mgw
> - Boost 1.43.0:
>     http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.43.0/boost_1_43_0.zip/download. Unzip to C:\boost-1.43.0-mgw
> - Boost Jam:
>     http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam/3.1.18/boost-jam-3.1.18-1-ntx86.zip/download. Unzip wherever you like, I used C:\bjam
> - miniUPnPc binary
>     http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/files/download.php?file=upnpc-exe-win32-20110215.zip.
>     Unzip to C:\upnpc-exe-win32-20110215
> - miniUPnPc source
>     http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/files/download.php?file=miniupnpc-1.5.20110215.tar.gz. Untar to C:\upnpc-exe-win32-20110215\miniupnpc (you only need *.h, but the others won't hurt) untar with cd \c\upnpc-exe-win32-20110215 && tar xvvf \c\Users\Matt\Downloads\miniupnpc-1.5.20110215.tar.gz && mv miniupnpc-1.5.20110215 miniupnpc
>
> Note that the reason for using the binary miniupnpc release is that I
>   was unable to get it to build on my system.
>
> Add C:\MinGW\bin to your PATH environment variable (Google is your
>   friend as it depends on your Windows Version).
>
> **In the DOS Shell:**
>
> wxWidgets:
>
> ```
> cd \wxWidgets-2.9.1-mgw\build\msw
> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc
> ```
>
> Boost:
>
> ```
> cd \boost-1.43.0-mgw
> \bjam\bjam.exe toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage
> ```
>
> **In the msys Shell (MinGW shell in your start folder or
>   C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat):**
>
> OpenSSL:
>
> ```
> cd /c/openssl-1.0.0c-mgw
> ./config
> make
> perl util/mkdef.pl 32 libeay enable-static-engine > libeay32.def
> dllwrap --dllname libeay32.dll --output-lib libeay32.a --def libeay32.def libcrypto.a -lws2_32 -lgdi32
> ```
>
> Copy the libeay32.dll file
>   to the folder where you are building/running bitcoin.
>
> Berkeley DB:
>
> ```
> cd /c/db-4.7.25.NC-mgw/build_unix
> sh ../dist/configure --enable-mingw --enable-cxx
> make
> ```
>
> **Bitcoin**
>
> If you wish to use git to pull keep a local repository, you'll have to
>   download msgit from
>   http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.4-preview20110204.exe&can=2&q= . Otherwise, you can download the latest zip of bitcoin from
>   https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/zipball/master In the msys shell,
>   cd to the unzipped location and
>
> ```
> make -f makefile.mingw
> ```
>
> Run with ./bitcoin.exe (make sure you have the libeay32.dll in bitcoin
>   folder)