# Problem with Berkeley DB while building Bitcoin on Windows from Source Code?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, compiling

I'm trying to compile Bitcoin from source code in Windows 7.
When I run `./configure`, I get the following error:

```
checking for Berkeley DB C++ headers... no
configure: error: libdb_cxx headers missing
```

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the source code folder `doc/build_msw`, but still get the same error.

Additionally, I have tried following these instructions for building Bitcoin on Windows:

- [How do I build Bitcoin source in Windows 7?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/587/how-do-i-build-bitcoin-source-in-windows-7)
- [Building headless Bitcoin and Bitcoin-qt on Windows](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0)

I have installed `berkeleydb 4.8.30.msi`.

What else can I try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything, but still its give me the same error

Comment: follow this links to resolve the issue https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0   and also installed with berkeleydb 4.8.30.msi, with command also installed

Comment: Please put sufficient information into your questions so that they can be answered by someone that is interested in trying to help you. This means that you need to provide background information, tell us what you have tried, and show us that you have put in reasonable effort to solve your problem yourself. Please don't add additional information into the comments, but **edit your question** to improve it. For additional information see [ask].

Comment: Have you tried installing berkleydb from source, as the forum page you linked tells you to do as step 2.2?

Comment: yes, I have done with source as well as with exe db-4.8.30.msi, still it will give the same error again and again

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a file in [doc/](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/doc) named `build_msw`. Are you building the latest version of Bitcoin?

Comment: I am usings bitcoin 0.9 version. and It will contain build-msw.md file. If I am use 0.10 version which is a latest code,  then how I can configure all dependencies for windows.

Comment: When you run the configure script and compile berkleydb, does it produces any output or error messages?

Comment: when I compile berkeley DB with its source code, It will compile perfectly. But when I run ./configure command from bitcoin code it will give me error that "checking for Berkeley DB C++ headers... no
configure: error: libdb_cxx headers missing"